# How can i use qcut to label all data by training data's value?

Tags: python, pandas

qcut is a great function in pandas.

But in a normal machine learning situation, we usually need to split data into training data and testing data.

let me list an example:

I have a dataset which contains 7 data.

```
In [5]: pd.qcut([1,4,3,2,5,3,4], 3, labels=False)
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1])
```

but what i want is only qcut based on the first 5 elements.
and the last two, label by the previous 5.

So, the first 5 should get labels like this:

```
In [6]: pd.qcut([1,4,3,2,5], 3, labels=False)
Out[6]: array([0, 2, 1, 0, 2])
```

and the last two should be `[2, 1]`

Is there any elegant method i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `cut` as work around

```
x = pd.qcut([1,4,3,2,5], 3)
out = pd.cut([1,4,3,2,5,3,4],bins = list(x.categories.left)+[np.inf],labels = range(3))
out
Out[182]: 
[0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]
Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 < 2]
```

Comment: great! thanks beny. if my input is pd.Series, what should i use to replace with x.categories? because series object dont have categories.